# is there a way to fix this through video editting?

Tags: video, playback

I recorded a video on my phone using a different camera app and it ended like this:

[image]

It feels like the video got split in to two if you can understand what i'm trying to say. Is there a way to remedy this using software?

Comment: I think you need to upload a portion of the video in order for people to have a better idea of the problem...

Answer (score 1):

I can't tell for sure from the single frame there and not knowing what the source was, but it appears that you were using an HDR video application.  The result of such an application is that you get frames with two different exposure settings that are designed to be combined to form video with frames that have a higher dynamic range.

If that conclusion is correct, then yes, you should be able to split the video in half, merge the two parts of the frame back together and produce an HDR video from that data.  You will need to control how you merge them back together using a typical HDR technique, which you can find many details about how to do online from photo resources.  The process for video is the same, it just gets bulk applied to all the pairs of frames.

It is worth noting that the overall resolution of the video may have suffered as a result of splitting the frame like that and there won't be any way to get back any lost resolution, but you should at least be able to get it reduced to a single video.

If I'm wrong in those assumptions though and the video frames are not individually correct, then there may be more complex blending that needs to be done and it may be specific to that application.  Does the application have an option to export the video after processing?  Whatever the application was, that seems like a very odd final output unless it is either expecting only basic processing to need to be done or it is expecting that that file is only an intermediate stage.